# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getClientRects' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jsx, typeerror

I'm new to ***React*** and I'm trying to implement this example: https://react-selectable-fast.now.sh/
I couldn't make it work, because I can't solve this error: ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'getClientRects' of null.***

This is my code:

> index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App items={[{player: "Dirk Nowitzki", year: 1999}, {player: "Magic Johnson", year: 1980}, {player: "Michael Jordan", year: 1990}]}/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

> App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { SelectableGroup } from 'react-selectable-fast'
import { createSelectable, SelectAll, DeselectAll } from 'react-selectable-fast'
import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent'

const SelectableComponent = createSelectable(SomeComponent)

class App extends Component {
    handleSelecting() {
        console.log("selecting");
    }

    handleSelectionClear() {
        console.log("selection clear");
    }

    handleSelectionFinish() {
        console.log("selection finish");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SelectableGroup
                className="main"
                clickClassName="tick"
                enableDeselect
                /*tolerance={this.state.tolerance}
                globalMouse={this.state.isGlobal}*/
                allowClickWithoutSelected={false}
                duringSelection={this.handleSelecting}
                onSelectionClear={this.handleSelectionClear}
                onSelectionFinish={this.handleSelectionFinish}
                ignoreList={['.not-selectable', '.item:nth-child(10)', '.item:nth-child(27)']}
            >
                <List items={this.props.items} />
            </SelectableGroup>
        )
    }
}

class List extends Component {
    render() {
        this.props.items.map((item, i) => {
            console.log(item.player, item.year, i);
        })
        return (
            <div>
                <SelectAll className="selectable-button">
                    <button>Select all</button>
                </SelectAll>
                <DeselectAll className="selectable-button">
                    <button>Clear selection</button>
                </DeselectAll>
                {this.props.items.map((item, i) => (
                    <SelectableComponent
                        key={i}
                        player={item.player}
                        year={item.year}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

> SomeComponent.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { createSelectable } from 'react-selectable-fast'

const SomeComponent = ({ selectableRef, isSelected, isSelecting }) => (
    <div ref={selectableRef} style={{
        border: "1px solid blue",
        width: "300px",
        height: "300px",
        float: "left",
    }}
         className="tick">...</div>
)

export default createSelectable(SomeComponent)
```

I also tried to delete ***node_modules*** and ***package-lock.json***, then made ***npm install***, but didn't work at all. I do not know if the error is from my code, because it has no reference to my jsx/js files. I noticed that I have 3 errors (for every objects in data array). Any help would be appreciated.

Screenshots of error:
[image: Error Image (1)]

[image: Error Image(2)]

Thanks in advance and have a great day!

Comment: Does your HTML have an element with `id="root"`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I have a `div` in html file with `id=root`. Thanks for the tip, I'll use forEach. I deleted that part of code, but still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was in `SomeComponent.jsx`.

***Solution:***

1. Delete

   ```
   export default createSelectable(SomeComponent)
   ```
2. And change

   ```
   const SomeComponent = ({ selectableRef, isSelected, isSelecting }) => (
   ```
3. Into

   ```
   export const SomeComponent = ({ selectableRef, isSelected, isSelecting }) => (
   ```